# проверка параметров в URL

Tags: php

Собственно вопрос:
Как в URL проверить, существуют ли указанные параметры. Их может быть 2..3..4
Например, если идет URL

`https://site.com?id=value` - то с этим вопросов нет. Понятно, как проверить.

Но как проверять параметры, если URL вида

`https://site.com?id=value&param2=value&param3=value` ?

В голову приходит только разбить его через explode и по циклу сверять..может есть способы лучше, подскажите

P.S.
Сам URL Rewrit'ится и становится вида `https://site.com/id/12/param2/value...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно взять `query` с помощью функции [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) и потом пройти по значению функцией [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) и на выходе получить ассоциативный массив, и там уже проверять как вам удобно, смотря что вы имеете в виду под проверкой.

```
$url = parse_url('https://site.com?id=value&param2=value&param3=value');
parse_str($url['query'], $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Вывод:

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(5) "value"
  ["param2"]=>
  string(5) "value"
  ["param3"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
```

Comment: под проверкой я подразумеваю..
Если в URL есть проверяемый параметр, то true..как то так. В голове либо in_array либо foreach + if

Comment: проще тогда empty($result['id'])

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: В общем с rewrite URL'ом это не работает

Comment: Если приходит `path`, то там нужно только цикл и разбивать по `/`, и смотреть по кратности это значение или ключ, вариант в ответе только для простого url.

Comment: Ну я так и понял..разбил explod'ом и через in_array проверил параметр..думал мб получше решение есть. Все равно полезен ответ )

Answer (score -1):

```
$url = 'https://site.com?id=value&param2=value&param3=value';

 parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);

 foreach ($query as $val=>$k) {

     if($val == 'param2') {
         echo '<pre>true</pre>';
     } else {
         echo '<pre>false</pre>';
     }
 }
```